# Python OpenCV split recording into multiple files

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use OpenCV and a webcam to continuously record video from the webcam for 15 minutes and then start the process again so that I have got 15 minute chunks of video.
I already wrote a script, but am experiencing unexpected behaviour. Recording works fine for a while and then the program would only create files that are 5kb in size that are not playable.

Would anybody know why that's happening?

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Record the current time
current_time = time.time()

#Specify the path and name of the video file as well as the encoding, fps and resolution
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/mnt/NAS326/cctv/' + str(time.strftime('%d %m %Y - %H %M %S' )) + '.avi', cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 15, (640,480))




while(True):



    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    out.write(frame)

    #If the current time is greater than 'current_time' + seconds specified then release the video, record the time again and start a new recording
    if time.time() >= current_time + 900:
        out.release()
        current_time = time.time()
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('/mnt/NAS326/cctv/' + str(time.strftime('%d %m %Y - %H %M %S' )) + '.avi', cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 15, (640,480))



out.release()

cap.release()




cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, you should test that `cap.read()` was sucessfull, and only write the frame if it is valid. That might have been causing problems with the output file. It is also better just to advance `next_time` when needed to avoid slight time slippages.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


def get_output(out=None):
    #Specify the path and name of the video file as well as the encoding, fps and resolution
    if out:
        out.release()
    return cv2.VideoWriter('/mnt/NAS326/cctv/' + str(time.strftime('%d %m %Y - %H %M %S' )) + '.avi', cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 15, (640,480))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
next_time = time.time() + 900
out = get_output()

while True:
    if time.time() > next_time:
        next_time += 900
        out = get_output(out)

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read() 

    if ret:
        out.write(frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```